# How to pivot dataframe without having to set index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
col1     value
test1     abc
test2     def
```

How do I flip the dataframe without having to add an `index` using `pivot_table`?

New df should look like this (without the existing column names ideally):

```
test1    test2
abc      def
```

edit:
df.T

```
gives me:
       abc    def
test1  1      0 
test2  0      1
```

Comment: Can you provide a more representative [mcve]? As of now, it isn't clear why df.transpose() isn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the [DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
In [2576]: df
Out[2576]: 
    col1 value
0  test1   abc
1  test2   def

In [2577]: df.T
Out[2577]: 
           0      1
col1   test1  test2
value    abc    def
```

Comment: I made an edit with what df.T gives me. Its not what I am looking for. I literally want the `value` column as rows under values from `col1` as columns.

Comment: I pasted the tested solution. Please check my answer. `df.T` works fine.